# Unable to find any alexa related skills as a blueprint while creating a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm creating a Custom Alexa skill and i'm using AWS Lambda ARN as endpoint.

Using AWS, I am trying to add a lambda function, using blueprint (the second option).
However when i search for alexa-skills blueprint, it says no data to display.
(keyword used : alexa)

Please note : I have already changed my region to all the recommended ones:-
N Virginia / Ireland / Tokyo

None of them seems to be working.

When i open https://blueprints.amazon.com/home
I get a message that says :"Your Amazon account is set to India. To create skills that you can use on your Alexa-enabled devices, your country setting must match your Blueprints website. Please call Customer Service for assistance."

Not sure if this is the reason but i verified my aws country settings and Alexa developer profile has same country selected to India.

Can some one please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like these have been moved. Under AWS Lambda, instead of choosing "Blueprints", choose "Browser Serverless App Repository" and then type "alexa" in the search bar. I see 28 apps you can try out, with instructions to activate, links to code repositories, etc.